# change reducer state from other reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This might be anti pattern but what I need to do is change another reducers state from other reducer. Not just access .

I need this because of redux-from , basically  I have to clear components form value , In my reducer I catch

```
case "@@redux-form/CHANGE":
  if (action.meta.form === "XXX") {..}
```

And process the value as I needed. According to my calcs I need to change components forms value which resides in

> form: reducerForm,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to the same action in both your reducers, and modify both of them.
This is not an anti-pattern, it's even recommended in the redux doc.

reducerA

```
case "@@redux-form/CHANGE":
  if (action.meta.form === "XXX") {..}
```

reducerB

```
case "@@redux-form/CHANGE":
  if (action.meta.form === "XXX") {..}
```

Comment: Redux-from allow you to write simple plugins to extend standard reducer , if follow this approach I have to write all ui managing logic inside of my combine reducer function which is of course not a good idea. Keeping form state in store would give me the abstraction but not at this cost . It is time to give up redux-from I guess and use simple formik. Thanks anyway